# Unable to link button to redirect to another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I use Visual Studio 2022 and I'm having trouble redirecting to another form to open when a button is clicked, It's unable to recognize the reference. I've tried using the Show and Hide technique but both don't work, just shows a red underline. worked earlier if the forms were placed in the same project drop down directory, I want to know if there is any way to refer to it. I'm using C#.

[image: Picture1]

[image: Picture2]

[image: Picture3]`

I'm new to C# and stack overflow and I'm making a project for my computer science coursework.

Comment: We prefer to see code as text, not images.  I don't see any red lines anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please read the tutorial and: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is a button click code note you create an instance of the form
The Hide is because it is used on the Main Startup Form of the Project
if it were another form just use Close();

```
    private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        frmSelect fSE = new frmSelect();
        fSE.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the problem is that the form you want to open is located in a different project. To access a form in another project you should add a reference to it. Just right click on your Gym Tracker App project --> Add --> Project Reference and then just check the other project.
Then simply put
`using Gym_Tracker_App`
int your frmLogin.cs